# Invalid date getting displayed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime

I know it is common error but I could not resolve it even after trying those answers.

Through the rest api I am sending some parameters inculdes dates. I am recieving all the data in the method where I want but when I am trying to parse Date it throws error of invalid date.

Here are my parameters that I am recieving

```
 {"uid"=>"1", "user"=>"abc.a@abc.com", "from"=>"Mon Nov 3 24:59:12 CET 2014", "to"=>"Tue Nov 11 24:59:12 CET 2014"}
```

and Date format is

```
Mon Nov 3 24:59:12 CET 2014
```

but it is throwing error on parsing on line below

```
 fr = DateTime.parse(params[:from]) unless params[:from].empty?
```

I tried strptime as well but did not work.

Imp points is I need hour also for later processing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing wrong is parsing `DateTime` while it is just date and should be parsed as one of the following ways:

1.

```
>> fr = params[:from].to_date unless params[:from].empty?
=>  Mon, 03 Nov 2014
```

2.

```
>> fr = Date.parse(params[:from]) unless params[:from].empty?
=> Mon, 03 Nov 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 24:59 which is invalid time. Anyway, use strptime:

```
DateTime.strptime("Mon Nov 3 22:59:12 CET 2014", "%a %b %e %T %Z %Y")
#=> Mon, 03 Nov 2014 22:59:12 +0100
```